# XML deserialization error with root

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I am having a problem while deserializing an XML:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message=There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
       at xsdToObject.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Old Documents\Projects\xsdToObject\xsdToObject\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Xml.XmlException
       Message=Root element is missing.
       Source=System.Xml
       LineNumber=0
       LinePosition=0
       SourceUri=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderentityColumnsColumnArray.Read3_ArrayOfEntityColumnsColumn()
       InnerException:
```

When going into the inner exception details the main error message is this:
{"Root element is missing."}

My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<entity name="ScheduleTaskEntity" schema="bclscheduler" namespace="http://www.bcl-gaming.com/data/1">
<columns>
<column name="Id" type="identity" />
<column name="UID" type="UID" />
<column name="Timestamp" type="timestamp"/>
<column name="DateCreated" type="datecreated"/>
<column name="Enabled" type="bool" />
<column name="TypeFullname" type="string" size="500" />
<column name="PropertiesLOB" type="propertybag" />
<column name="DisplayName" type="string" size="64" />
<column name="LastDateExecuted" type="datetime" nullable="true" />
<column name="LastMessage" type="string" />
<column name="LastSessionUID" type="guid" nullable="true" />
<column name="CurrentState" type="string" />
<column name="LastDateStarted" type="datetime" nullable="true"/>
<column name="SingleInstance" type="boolean" />
<column name="ExecuteCount" type="bigint" />
<column name="ErrorCount" type="bigint" />      
</columns>
</entity>
```

My code is as follows:

```
entity e;

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(entityColumnsColumn[]));
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Old Documents\Projects\xsdToObject\xsdToObject\ScheduleTaskEntityTest.xml");
reader.ReadToEnd();
//it gives me the error here
e = (entity)x.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
reader.ReadToEnd();
//it gives me the error here
e = (entity)x.Deserialize(reader);
```

The problem is the `reader.ReadToEnd()` - after this there is nothing to read anymore and only then you are trying to deserialize - this must fail. Instead just use the StreamReader directly:

```
using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\Old Documents\Projects\xsdToObject\xsdToObject\ScheduleTaskEntityTest.xml"))
{
    e = (entity)x.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Comment: Now im having the error:

{"<entity xmlns=''> was not expected."}

Comment: the error before was being occured on the line:

e = (entity)x.Deserialize(reader);

Comment: @Kurt: That sounds like a problem with your XML data now

Comment: The xml file was converted to xsd by the visualstudio command promt, and the data in the xml file is good for sure as there are other people who used this xml file before, the only problem is that they dont have the solution anymore....

Comment: Also why do you use `typeof(entityColumnsColumn[])` when it should be `typeof(entity)` - or are they the same?

Comment: when i use typeof entity this is the following error message:

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'entityColumnsColumn[]' to 'entityColumnsColumn'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'entityColumnsColumn' to 'entityColumnsColumn[]'

Comment: You'll have to show us some of your `entityColumnsColumn` class.

Comment: I just found out what the  problem was, when outputing the .cs file from the .xsd file in the visual studio 2010 comand prompt there is a bug, it does the entitiesColumnColumns[][] i had to remove all [][] to [] and that solved the problems! thanks to you all :)

Answer (score 1):

Specify the root attribute when deserializing at run time.

```
XmlRootAttribute xmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xmlRoot.ElementName = "entity";    
xmlRoot.IsNullable = true;

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Object),xmlRoot);
```